# Deduced conflicting types in template pack with reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm working on a program with following structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void fun(const std::string &text, int a, int b) { // (1)
    std::cout << text << a + b << std::endl;
}

template<typename ...Args>
void execute(void(*fun)(Args...), Args ...args) {
    fun(args...);
}

void init(const std::string &text, int a, int b) {
    execute(fun, text, a, b);
}

int main() {
    init("Fun: ", 1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

and I get the error message

```
.code.tio.cpp:14:2: error: no matching function for call to 'execute'
        execute(fun, text, a, b);
        ^~~~~~~
.code.tio.cpp:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Args' (<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &, int, int> vs. <std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, int>)
void execute(void(*fun)(Args...), Args ...args) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I can fix the error by removing the reference in line **(1)**:

```
void fun(const std::string text, int a, int b) {
```

but I want to pass the values by reference and not by value. The function template

```
template<typename ...Args>
void execute(void(*fun)(Args...), Args ...args)
```

must not be changed. How can I fix this so that `text` is passed by reference,  `execute` is not changed and `init` is also not changed if possible?

EDIT:
@super showed that I was wrong and I have to reformulate my requirements. `execute` can only be modified to the extent that other projects that have a dependency on this function don't break. I didn't think about such a solution.

Comment: You have code that is not working, but you don't want to change it? I don't understand what you're looking for in that case.

Comment: @super I can't change `execute` as it is a generic function from a framework used in many different projects. It's not possible to change it. `init` can be changed but it would be expensive. `fun` can be changed because it is a new function that must work with the generic framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without touching `execute`, I think you have to change `init()`. One way would be to explicitely pass the template argument (bypassing the argument deduction in order to transport the reference type information):

```
void init(const std::string &text, int a, int b) {
    execute<const std::string&>(fun, text, a, b);
}
```

Comment: trying to compile it gives `Error C2782 'void execute(void (__cdecl *)(Args...),Args...)': template parameter 'Args' is ambiguous`
`

Comment: I only see a "hello world" file

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion: use two set of template variadic parameters

```
template <typename ... As1, typename ... As2>
void execute(void(*fun)(As1...), As2 ... args) {
    fun(args...);
}
```

This way you can maintain the reference in the `fun()` function argument and pass to it a string value.

More in general: it's a nightmare impose that the deduced set of the arguments of the function is exactly the same set of the following arguments.  And it's not necessary.

Suppose you have function `foo()` that receive a `long`

```
void foo (long)
 { }
```

and you call `execute()` passing a the `foo()` pointer and a `int`

```
execute(foo, 1);
```

If you use a single `Args...` variadic sequence, the call fail as in your question because the compiler deduce `Args...` as `long` (from `foo()` signature) and `long` (from the value `1`), so an ambiguity.

If you use two variadic sequences, the compiler deduce `long` for `As1...`, deduce `int` for `As2...`, there is no ambiguity and `execute()` pass a `int` value to a function that expects a `long` value and this is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you don't want to change `execute`, but modifying it to use a separate template parameter for the callable would be the best approach in my opinion.

This has the added benefit that you could pass in any callable, like a lambda or a `std::function` or functor.

Adding perfect forwarding is an additional good idea. The callable could arguably be forwarded as well to be as generic as possible.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void execute(F fun, Args&& ...args) {
    fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

If the signature of the function is important, and that's why you don't want to modify `execute` there are ways to extract that from `F` with type traits.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work since one of the Arguments is `const&` - as you probably already noticed. These keywords can be eliminated by creating a helper struct that holds a const reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional> 

template<typename T>
struct const_ref {
    const_ref(const T& value) : value(value) {}
    const std::reference_wrapper<const T> value;
};

void fun(const_ref<std::string> text, int a, int b) {
    std::cout << text.value.get() << a + b << std::endl;
}

template<typename ...Args>
void execute(void(*fun)(Args...), Args ...args) {
    fun(args...);
}

void init(const std::string &text, int a, int b) {
    const_ref<std::string> refstring{ text };
    execute(fun, refstring, a, b);
}

int main() {
    init("Fun: ", 1, 2);
}
```

this way `extecute()` isn't altered. It's also not too hard to maintain as additional parameters that should be `const T&` can simply be declared `const_ref<T>`.